# sql, не видит строки при условии со знаком =

Tags: mysql

При запросе
`SELECT * FROM base_stock_cloth_rol WHERE rol_count='39.8'`

получаю ответ MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк) [Screanshort1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhOCk.png)

А при запросе

```
SELECT * FROM base_stock_cloth_rol WHERE rol_count>'39'
```

получаю в ответ уже не пустой запрос Отображение строк 0 - 16 [Screanshort2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxpiB.png)

*P.S.   тип столбца rol_count - float 

P.S.2  без ' ' тоже пробовал результат всё равно пустой*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В базе, скорее всего, хранится число только приблизительно равное `39.8`. Если тип колонки - четырех-байтный float, число `39.8` просто не может быть выражено абсолютно точно этим типом данных. Вам придется компоновать условие вида:

```
... WHERE rol_count > 39.799 AND rol_count < 39.801
```

или

```
... WHERE ABS(rol_count - 39.8) < 0.001
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то уже сижу и думаю то ли спать уже пора, толи лыжи не едут. Второй вариант более чем подходит